# Nested mapping configurations (existing configuration inside another)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

This project I'm working has too many nested objects, and each of these objects has different mappings based on the context.
For example, if I map an outer class with an inner class, the inner class mapping must behave in a different way than if I map the inner class directly.
The mapping of the inner class (or outer, all classes really) is retrieved by a method that returns it's MapperConfiguration based on the parameters it receives. That way I can write the MapperConfiguration once for each class. The problem is, I can't find a way to call this method inside another MapperConfiguration, "mixing" the configurations, like a cascade effect.
I tried using profiles, but it makes me write "CreateMap" for all the profiles that needs this inner class mapping, or I have to add the profile of the inner class and it's childs inside the MapperConfiguration of the outer class. This will be difficult to mantain, since the objects are too complex. Is there a way to achieve this "cascade effect" using automapper?
Edit: Maybe I can be more clear if I say what is the core of the problem: I want to know if it is possible to the get all the profiles (or the mappings configurations expressions) from an MapperConfiguration so I can add them in another.

Comment: It is a little bit confusing on the scenario you have. On the one hand you want to provide only specific mappings based on the "root" object, so the inner objects are mapped in a specific way defined on the context of the "root" object. But on the other hand you want to reuse mappings/configurations, which contradicts the goal to provide individual mappings. What is it now, same or different mappings depending on the context? Please [edit] your question to include the (sample) classes you have, the mappings you want to use, the result you want to get and the problems you have.

Comment: If it's so complex, then perhaps it's business logic and it doesn't belong hidden in some AM config? Anyway, try `MapperConfigurationExpression`. That allows you to reuse configuration between different `MapperConfiguration`s.